# Task Manager is not able to run due to compatibility issues.

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-8.1, task-manager

I am not able to open the Task Manager through keyboard shortcuts and by right-clicking the taskbar, I even tried launching it through Command Promp to no avail. Whenever I launch it by using the keyboard shortcuts it keeps saying that "This App Can't Run on your PC" and gives me incompatibility issues with 64-bit version Windows. Please help me.....The Task Manager is an essential part of the OS.

Comment: The computer may be infected with a virus (ref: [Troubleshoot Task Manager problems](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/troubleshoot-task-manager-problems)).

Comment: Your system is corrupt you will need to repair the sustme image before you can do anything

Comment: I had a virus and some malwares before.......when I finally cleaned them I got the "cannot find taskmgr.exe in System32" error and sure enough, taskmgr.exe wasn't present in the folder. After searching the internet long enough, I decided to perform a System restore which later resulted in this compatibility error. P.S I am able to run 32-bit version of taskmgr.exe

Answer (score 0):

This issue could occur if some of your Operating system files are corrupted,  please try the System File Checker tool,  follow these steps:

> Open CMD prompt using "Run as administrator" option.
>
> At the command prompt, try the command:
> sfc/scannow

Once the scan finishes check the status. If still the issue persists,  as you have already tried system restore,  you can try performing an OS repair using your OS Disk.